# jQuery deep cloning not working with plugin attached elements

Tags: jquery, clone

I've the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap-toggle.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="old">
        <input type="checkbox" class="chck" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="new">

    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="my.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

bootstrap-toggle.min.js converts checkboxes into beautiful toggle switches. I'm cloning the above checkbox and appending into the "id=new" div using the following code:

```
var clone = $('#old').clone(true, true).appendTo('#new');
```

The code works just fine and appends the whole html copy of cloned element.

But the problem is, both toggle switches don't work separate at individual level. Only the first toggle switch responds to click actions on all switches.

Why deep jquery cloning is not preserves the plugin attached to each cloned element?

Even I changed the html as below using classes

```
<div class="col-md-6 first">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 second">

    </div>

var clone = $('.first').clone(true, true).appendTo('.second');
```

This code also behaves same as the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You realize that ids must be unique to the page yes?  It looks like your cloning something based on id and then appending it to the page again without altering it's id, which would make it non-unique and invalid html.

Comment: Ok let me try using class

Comment: May not be the entire issue, but definitely a smell.

Comment: The code is also not working. I've updated the question